# \ref does not work

Tags: cross-referencing

I want to write a paper. There are three Chapters. In the first chapter, I got a Corollary and I labeled it as following:

```
Corollary 1 \label{cor:1}
```

In the second chapter, I want to cite the "Corollary 1", I input

```
Corollary  \ref {cor:1}.
```

After running pdflatex, it shows the following:

> Corollary ??.

without the number "1"

How do I tackle this problem?

Comment: Do you write `Corollary 1` manually? `\label`s only work properly when they attach to a counter. Usually people write their corollaries using a `theorem`-like environment. See for example https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/theorems_and_proofs

Comment: The purpose of the `\label` / `\ref` set up is so that you don't write the 1.  That way, you are free to rearrange your corollaries without having to go through the entire document to fix every 1.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) In order for the community to help you easier, please consider adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @moewe, When I cite the proposition or theorem , it reveals  the number correctly . For example, there is a theorem \ref{thm} in Chapter1,  when I input the code : \ref{thm}, after running pdflatex, it reveals the correct label

Comment: @Teepeemm, acutually the label of corollary is 1.1.21. When I cite the corollary in the other chapters, how to change the code to let it reveal the correct number 1.1.21?

Comment: @moewe, I have reedited the problem

Comment: Sorry, without a full example document (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows what you are actually doing I won't be able to say anything useful. `\label` and `\ref` will only work when they can attach to a counter, so far I can't tell whether there will be a counter in your document.

Comment: `??` is the _expected_ output for the first run have you reun latex again until it doesnot give a "re-run latex" warning?  Unrelated but `{cor:1}` it is bad practice to use numbers in label arguments, it confuses any humans looking at the source when the number in the label  is not the same as the printed number.

Answer (score 1):

This is a MWE on using the `\label` inside a `corollary` environment, defined thanks to the `amsthm` package.
Apparently, from the question no environment is used to define the corollary, thus explaining the undesired output of the `\ref` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\begin{document}
\begin{corollary}
    This is a corollary
    \label{the-corollary}
\end{corollary}
Let's make a reference to corollary~\ref{the-corollary}.
\end{document}
```

[image]